# How to split a total into smaller disaggregates that match the total it was split from

Tags: arithmetic, fair-division

I need to resolve the following in computer language. I  have situations that I have to split totals in smaller various disaggregations.

A client gets data from clinics around a district. However they only get totals instead of dis-aggregates of those totals. They are asking to calculate the dis aggregates based off of fixed fractions or based of historical fractions they will provide. However when I do use fractions, very often I find they don't equal the total provided. I need to total to match the sum of dis aggregations.

I must calculate an estimate for the number of new patients per gender and age group that visited a clinic every day for every day of the year but I may only use whole numbers. This works OK for large amount but for small amount I get a problem
For example 3 new patients visited the clinic that day. I need to split it into 10 age groups and genders  and the total must match the day total I was given

I get given fixed/historical fractions  for the disaggregates
e.g.

- 1:0.1
- 2:0.1
- 3:0.15
- 4:0.15
- 5:0.2
- 6:0.1
- 7:0.1
- 8:0.0.05
- 9:0.025
- 10:0.025

Total fractions equal 100%

If 5 new patients visited the clinic I get the following disaggregations

- 1:0.1 * 5 rounded = 1
- 2:0.1 * 5 rounded = 1
- 3:0.1 * 5 rounded = 1
- 4:0.2 * 5 rounded = 1
- 5:0.2 * 5 rounded = 1
- 6:0.1 * 5 rounded = 1
- 7:0.1 * 5 rounded = 1
- 8:0.0.05* 5 rounded = 0
- 9:0.025 * 5 rounded = 0
- 10:0.025 * 5 rounded = 0

So my total is 7 instead of 5.  2 more than I want.

If 2 new patients visit the clinic my total is 0, 2 less than I want.

Is there something in Mathematics that can assist me in making the sum of the disaggregations match the original total or is this not a Maths problem?

Comment: I don't understand why you aren't using the actual ages of the 5 new patients, rather than a set of predetermined ratios. Surely the predetermined ratios are based on historical data. But it seems like you want to see what the percentage of genders/ages are going forward.

Comment: Using naive rounding means the totals might not match correctly.  What would you like to do about that?  There are a variety of choices open to you, but it is unclear what purpose would be served by doing what you suggest, so Readers are in a poor position to recommend a particular option.

Comment: I only want it to match. I don't have any purpose apart from having it match mathematically. No need to overthink it

Answer (score 0):

What mathematics can do with the requirements you have described
is to show that they have absurd results.
In fact, you have already used mathematics to show this.

We can list some circumstances under which such absurd
requirements can be placed on a software program:

1. You did not correctly understand what the requirements were, and you are trying to implement the software to incorrect requirements.
2. The person(s) who set the requirements did not correctly understand what they were asking for, and set requirements whose results will be an unpleasant surprise to them.
3. The person(s) who set the requirements knew exactly what they were doing, and set the requirements in such a way that even though some of the results look absurd in isolation, some overall goal is achieved.

In any of those three circumstances, what I do is to go back to the person(s) who set the requirements and try to get further explanation of what they really want.
One technique to discover what people really want is to give them some simple examples, such as the ones you have presented, and ask what a suitable result would be.

It is possible that nobody really wanted an estimate of exactly how many patients in group 1 attended the clinic on May 1, but they do want to know how many patients in group 1 attended the clinic in May, how many attended on Monday (adding together the attendance for all Mondays that year), and some other statistics like that. Perhaps they thought (mistakenly) that the best way to get such statistics was to have an estimated list of how many patients  in each group attended on each individual day.

Or perhaps you are supposed to take a list of patients for the entire year,
belonging to each of the ten groups in the proportions given,
and randomly assign them to different days of the year according to the  number of patients who actually arrived on each day, to support
some sort of Monte Carlo analysis.

Or perhaps you are just supposed to round exactly the way you said,
with a disclaimer such as "numbers in this column may not sum to the actual total due to rounding."

We should not have to guess *why* you were given a set of requirements in
a particular form, and you should not have to guess either, at least not in
cases like this where the reasons for the requirements might cause a larger project to fail.

Comment: I don't want to prove it is absurd result. I want to have a formula that make it match.

Comment: For the case you showed with a sum of 7 where you wanted 5, you could randomly choose two of the five 1s that were rounded up from 0.5 and make them 0. Be aware that this sort of thing could mess up the statistics, depending on what someone wants to do with the data. The only *professional* response, in my opinion, is to seek for a clarification or modification of the requirements.

Comment: The requirements are they want to support drilldowns in map form and drill down to dis-aggregate level. The disaggregate should be the sum of the totals. However since the disaggregate data never existed it is calculated based of fixed fraction or based of historical data. The reason is that not all facilities provide dis aggregate information but instead just have a total patient count. Some facilities do have disaggregates reported but other do not. Should individual age range statistic analysis be removed because of some facilities having not data?

Comment: The data you want it the aggregate data and that should be the absolute truth and not the incorrect sum of dis-aggregates which are used for additional analysis and various reports. I need a formula that is consistent for 100s of facilities. I don't want manual adjustment. Rather a mathematical sound split

Comment: You (or your clients) need advice from a professional statistician. I suspect the answer to "should age range analysis be removed" is likely "yes," at least with respect to facilities that don't record it. But this is not something on which to get advice from strangers on the internet.

Comment: The client gets dictated by a 3rd party party's BI tool that they must report the disaggregates and everything tallies up to the total. Surely it can be solved mathematically without telling them it is not possible and you shouldn't report the disaggregates. That's like me telling to change their BI tool because it requires disaggregates for all facilties

Comment: Has your client called customer support for the tool to ask what to do about this? There should be a feature in the tool to deal with this problem, which happens a lot in the real world. Or maybe your client _should_ change their tool, but I'd give the vendor a chance to fix the problem first.